# Aws Cognito with google federated identity: Logs me in with the last user

Tags: google-oauth, amazon-cognito

**Problem:**
I am using Aws Cognito using google as external federated identity for auth of my application: 
problem is it logs me in with the last user when having only one signed in google account. Basically it seem its simply not able to logout the user completely.

**Heres what is happening :**

- I am logged into google with e.g user a@gmail.com
- I login into cognito via the external federated identity use the above email and login. All iz well.
- I now logout and want to login into cognito using 'b@gmail.com', now say I created the account using another browser and never used the current browser, so browser does not know about this.(In short I am logged into just one gmail account in this browser.)
- When I try to signin I am shown the option to 'Signin with Google' but it never presents me the account selection screen and directly logs me in.

I am using the screen cognito shows at https://mydomain.auth.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login

**Using Prompt:**

I see that google itself has a way to force the user to select an account using the 'prompt' : select_account option. But I see no way to specify this anywhere in cognito.

**Question :** 
- Anyone have any fix / workaround to above problem? I need a way to 'always' show the account selection so that he can choose or use a different account.

**Did you try the logout endpoint from cognito ?**
- Yes, This is happening even after I send the user to the logout endpoint of cognito, which is probably supposed to logout the user.

Comment: Have been experiencing the same thing, I've even tried with openid connect without success. Have you found a workaround?

Comment: @AdrienRusso : No, we did raise a support ticket with Amazon and they did acknowledge the issue but have no timeframe as to when they will fix.

Comment: Any updates on this? Been investigating the same issue.

Comment: @VDog: No We still experience it and there is no fix in sight.

Comment: I think we might be able to manually pass the code back from fb to cognito, and either manually do this with Facebook or use the facebookSDK. Another possible approach is the rn auth package but feeling less hopeful about the latter.

Comment: After 1 year, were you able to solve the issue? We are getting the same issue - although in our case our identity provider is auth0 instead of google. We call logout endpoint upon user logout, and it even redirects to app logout url. But opening the login url again for a new login doesn't work, it still returns the previous session.

Comment: I laso have the same issue. I need to sign out Cognito user (using federated OIDC IdP). I found out that the logout endpoint (with the redirect to my app via logout_uri) works in Chrome, but not in other browsers.